# How to set different default formatters in VSCode settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to set different default formatters for different languages in VSCode? I want VSCode to autodetect the language used in current file and use the appropriate editor. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15):

You can press `Ctrl` + `,` keys to access the settings in VS Code, and then type in @lang:`language-name` Default Formatter (e.g @lang:html Default Formatter) or just scroll down to where it says Editor: Default Formatter and then choose the formatter for that language.

[image: Reference image for more clarificarion]

Comment: For years i have been suffering from this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You can edit your settings.json file and type these depending on which language you want to use. In my case I have a formatter for HTML and a separate one for Javascript:

```
{
     "[html]": {
         "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
     },
     "[javascript]": {
         "editor.defaultFormatter": "remimarsal.prettier-now"
     }
}
```